# How to check if a query returned some values? (MySQL, Php)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating a registration system and I want to have a query that checks if the username the user entered doesn't exist yet or is not owned by another person yet. But so far I've been unsuccessful. I tried looking at some of the questions and answers that were related to mine but most I couldn't understand or most didn't work out for me. Please also keep in mind that I am an amateur in PHP.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "php24sql", "some password","smithside");
$query2 = "SELECT registered FROM contacts WHERE LRN = '$lrn'";
$query2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
$registered = $row['registered'];
if ($registered == 0) {
$query = "UPDATE contacts SET first_name = '$fname', last_name = '$lname', position = 'none', email = '$email', phone = '$contact', user_name = '$uname', password = '$pass1', access = 'Registered', registered = 1 WHERE LRN = '$lrn'";
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
echo "Registration successful!";

$query4 = "SELECT user_name FROM contacts WHERE user_name = '$uname'";
$query4 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query4); 
$row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query4);
} elseif (mysql_num_rows($query4) > 0) {
echo "Registration failed. Username already taken.";
} else {
echo "Registration failed. LRN already taken.";
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Look into num_rows http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: `} elseif (mysql_num_rows($query4) > 0) {` you got the typo in this line means you are missing `i` in `mysql` change that line to this `} elseif (mysqli_num_rows($query4) > 0) {`

Answer (score 0):

```
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($num_rows == 0)
{
//user name doesn't exist
}
else
{
//user name exists
}
```

You're looking for `mysqli_num_rows` function - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

---

Additionally you can make field in db "UNIQUE", then all the time, when you  submit value, which already exist, MySQL will return error.

---

**PS** There is **fatal SQL Injection** security bug in your code. Before you send any values to DB, you have to "clean" them from special characters - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php you can use this function to implement that!